# Use Regex to remove anything duplicate

Tags: vb.net

I have a text box with value 13356689. I want to use regex to remove the duplicate value, i want to return 135689. I don't know the type of this value in text box, text or integer or digit or anything. I used The ways but I failed. Please help. Thanks

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1\b)+", "${1}", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Regex.Replace(string, @"(.)(\1)+", "$1"))
Regex.Replace(string, @"(?<1>\w)(?<=\k<1>\w*?.)+", string.Empty)
New Regex("(?<=(.))\1+").Replace(string, "")
```

But i failed.

Comment: `dim test as string = "13356689"  dim distinct as string = string.Concat(test.Distinct())`

Answer (score 0):

```
Char last=Nothing
String newsgroup=“”
for a as integer =0 to input.length-1
    If last=nothing or not last=input[a]
        Newsgroup+= input[a]

    End if
        Last=input[a]
Next
Return newsgroup
```

This will be better than using regex. It involves basic string manipulation only.